# Native Query with array in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

I want to make a query verify value as contained into array in Postgres. I made a nativeQuery in JPA the query apparently is correct and is working in DBeaver(DBM), but not in java application.

[image: Dbeaver query working],
[image: Application log]

```
    ERROR: operator does not exist: integer[] @> character varying
    TIP: No operator matches the name and type of the argument. You need to add explicit type conversions.
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not supported in native queries as they directly delegate to JDBC drivers which do not support it.

When you use a JPQL like this:

```
var query = em.createQuery("select p from Person p where p.name in :names", Person.class);
query.bind("names", List.of("A", "B");
```

And then check the generated native SQL, then you will see, that the generated SQL looks something like:

```
select .. from person where person.name in (?, ?)
```

In your case I am affraid you will have to generate the query dynamically with something like:

```
var entries = List.of("A","B");
var sql = new StringBuilder("select ... from person where person.name in (");
for (var i=0; i<entries.size(); i++) {
    sql.append('?');
    if (i<entries.size()-1) sql.append(',');
}
sql.append(')');
var query = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
for (var i=0; i<entries.size(); i++) {
    query.setParameter(i+1, entries.get(i));
}
```